# Dividir una importación pesada en varias Script PHP

Tags: php, webservice, script, prestashop

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un script de importación de datos hacia Prestashop via Webservice. Este script plantea una serie de problemas a afrontar, y uno de ellos es la importación de grandes cantidades de datos a la plataforma.

El script reporta un **error 503** siempre que llega sobre los **300 segundos**, lo que me hace pensar que está dando timeout. La solución más rápida para este problema sería simplemente aunmentar el tiempo de ejecución máximo del script y su memoria caché, pero esto no es una via disponible.

Por lo tanto, me ha planteado varios caminos como el de realizar más llamadas **CRON** al script para realizar múltiples ejecuciones hasta que se termine la importación total de los datos, pero no sé cómo guardar el avance de estos y en general no tengo un buen conocimiento de estas. En segundo lugar, me he planteado que cada **X productos** el script serialice y almacene la información restante en un archivo `.bin`, para posteriormente ejecutarlo de nuevo utilizando esa información almacenada.

```
        if(!file_exists($store)){
        $xmlContent = file_get_contents($originXmlPath . $archive);
        $sanitizedXmlContent = preg_replace ('/[^\x{0009}\x{000a}\x{000d}\x{0020}-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}]+/u', ' ', $xmlContent);
        $products = simplexml_load_string($sanitizedXmlContent);
    }else {
        $products = unserialize(file_get_contents($store));
        $products = simplexml_load_string($products);
    }

    foreach ($products as $product) {

        if ($time > 25) {
            file_put_contents($store, serialize($sanitizedXmlContent));
            exec('nohup PATH -f script.php');
            exit(1);
        } 
        unset($serializedXmlContent->$product)

      }
```

Mi principal problema con esta manera de enfocar el problema es que el script no vuelve a ejecutarse después de realizar `exit()`.

No tengo muy claro cúal es la mejor manera de enfocar este problema. Cualquier documentación me servirá de ayuda u opiniones sobre el tema. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: @Trauma como he comentado en el post, no puedo hacer uso de estas dos vias usando `ini_set()`, aún así los tengo con valores altos. No funciona.

Comment: Ah, cierto. Perdón, no lo ví.

Comment: Se puede hacer con un contador de avance y un llamado ajax que itera sobre sí mismo hasta que el contador llega al límite deseado o el servidor devuelva una marca de fin de proceso. En cada llamado la página envía un bloque de datos y al recibir done del servidor autoajusta el contador, valida si termina o continua, y si no termina itera el llamado. Yo uso ese mecanismo con éxito para simular batch.

Comment: Luego podrás mejorarlo interpolando qué hacer si hay error, mensajes de avance, y mecanismos de interrupción.

Comment: @quevedo el script realiza petiticiones a webservice mediante URL, pero este script es llamada mediante una llamada `CRON` ¿Cómo podría implementar esta llamada `AJAX` en el script para que se llame así mismo? ¿Las llamadas `AJAX` también sirven para realizar llamadas a ficheros dentro de un servidor?

Comment: La llamada ajax es de hecho un llamado a una url. Desde la llamada CRON puedes invocar un script que controle las iteraciones.

Answer (score 1):

Para abordar este tipo de problemas, lo mejor es **caracterizar el proceso**:

1.- **Identificar** dónde esta el cuello de botella.
¿Es prestashosp o tu script?, ¿Es el parseo del XML o la sanitización con expresión regular?.

2.- **Observar** con las herramientas del sistema operativo para identificar cuál recurso se agota
(ej. memoria física, de intercambio o cache, espacio en disco) y/o el que se usa más intensamente (ej. lectura/escritura a disco, red, procesador, base de datos);
suelen saltar a la vista.

3.- **Cuantificar**. Normalmente encontrarás un relación directa entre el número de elementos a procesar (ej. número archivos, registros o líneas) y la duración del(los) cuello(s) de botella.

El primer ejercicio sería intercalar mensajes con hora, minuto y segundo antes de cada bloque principal de código,
o incluso entre cada línea; donde haya la mayor diferencia profundizar hasta donde sea posible.

Dependiendo de los hallazgos, la solución podría ser un comando simple, un cambio de configuración, aumento de recursos,
y en el peor de los casos implementar alguna de las técnicas para **procesos de larga duración** como: procesos asíncronos, colas de mensajes, subprocesos, multi-hilos, etc..